# Words or phrases to state that taking factors into consideration at first place.

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Are there any words or phrases to state that taking factors into consideration at first place?

For example, maybe before I start to write a patent, I take potential rivals, expected costs and profits, target clients into consideration. 
How do I express this idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: All things considered: after carefully thinking about all the facts.

Comment: Why do you think the way you said it is not good enough? It seems clear and concise.

Comment: That is because I need to express this idea in a title, and the way I say it, in my opinion, is too long for a title. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Proactive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/proactive)*** ***consideration***:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> (Of a person, policy, or action) creating or controlling a situation
> by causing something to happen rather than responding to it after it
> has happened:

Or

***Proactive [examination](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/examination):***

> NOUN
>
> 1 A detailed inspection or investigation:
>
> Origin
>
> late Middle English (also in the sense 'testing (one's conscience) by
> a standard'): via Old French from Latin *examinatio*(n-), from *examinare*
> '*weigh*, *test*' (see examine).

Or as the definition of examination suggests:

***Proactive investigation***

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It is very helpful to me. However, I am not sure about the usage. Can I say that "I wrote this patent proactively" ? or that "I wrote this patent with proactive consideration". For me, who may not be right, the former sounds weird, and the latter sounds reasonable.

Comment: ***Proactive*** would not describe your writing as effectively as the **investigation** that supported your writing. Proactive investigation would be one element of ***careful*** writing--or **thorough**, **thoughtful**, **accurate**, **deliberate**, **meticulous**, **precise** writing.

Comment: Thank you very much about your reply. I recently still focus on this question while I read. I found an interesting word when I read about the suffix pre: preliminary. Can i say it is a preliminary consideration?